# undefined method `rates' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I need to do is create a page where the user will type in a last name and the system will return information related to it. I keep receiving the error undefined method `rates' for nil:NilClass and am not sure why any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for bookin_controller.rb (@rate_list = r.rates is throwing the error)

```
class BookinController < ApplicationController

def bookin


end
  def bookout
  @customer_name = params[:customer_name_in]
   r = Customer.find_by_last(@customer_name)
   @rate_list = r.rates
  end
end
```

Here is the rate.rb controller

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base


validates :season, :room, :cost, presence: true 

has_many :bookings
  has_many :customers, :through => :bookings

end
```

Comment: `variable r` returned `nil`,so use `@rate_list = r.try(:rates)`,`try` will work in rails 3 and more.

Answer (score 3):

```
r = Customer.find_by_last(@customer_name)
```

returned `nil`. There was no match. That is all.

If you want to safely apply `rates` method in that case, giving `nil` when `r` is `nil`, then do:

```
@rate_list = r.rates if r
```

Comment: Wow then is something wrong with my code in my customer customer.rb `class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base




  has_many :rates, :through => :bookings 
  has_many :bookings

 def mail_list
    "#{first} - #{last} - #{maillist}"
  end
end`

Comment: This has nothing to do with your model code. Sawa meant that you don't have any record in `customers` table with `last = params[:customer_name_in]`. So `r` becomes `nil` as there was no match.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have any matching records with that query, so it returned `nil`.

Instead try like this

```
def bookout
  @customer_name = params[:customer_name_in]
  @r = Customer.find_by_last(@customer_name)
  @rate_list = @r ? @r.rates : nil
  end
```

Or you can replace `@rate_list = @r ? @r.rates : nil` with `@rate_list = @r.try(:rates)`

```
def bookout
  @customer_name = params[:customer_name_in]
  @r = Customer.find_by_last(@customer_name)
  @rate_list = @r.try(:rates)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I have one more question I have a table named Customer with a field title of last why can it not find it?

Comment: @user3281827 Because @customer_name is returning nil.Make sure it is not `nil`.

Comment: @user3281827 If my solution is worked for yoy,then please accept my answer.

Comment: it did not I have a table named customer with entries in it, I am not sure why it can't find them

Comment: @user3281827 Try posting a sample record of your table in the Question.